# Why do different vector<bool> elements share the same address?

Tags: c++

I have defined the following class.

```
class STTreeNode
{
public:
    int ind;
    int parentInd;  
    std::vector<int> childInds;

    int numTrain;
    std::vector<bool> isInfluenced;

    STTreeNode(int ind, int parentInd, int numTrain);
};

STTreeNode::STTreeNode(int ind, int parentInd, int numTrain) {
    this->ind = ind;
    this->parentInd = parentInd;
    this->numTrain = numTrain;
}
```

and I ran the following code snippet.

```
STTreeNode *a = new STTreeNode(3, 4, 5);
a->childInds.push_back(20);
a->childInds.push_back(30);
a->isInfluenced.push_back(true);
a->isInfluenced.push_back(false);

for (int i = 0; i < a->childInds.size(); i++)
    std::cout << &(a->childInds[i]) << " ";
std::cout << std::endl;
for (int i = 0; i < a->isInfluenced.size(); i++)
    std::cout << &(a->isInfluenced[i]) << " ";
std::cout << std::endl;
```

The output was

```
0000020351C18520 0000020351C18524
00000083540FFC60 00000083540FFC60
```

I am very confused about this. Why do the two elements in `a->childInd`s have consecutive addresses (as expected), while the two elements in `a->isInfluenced` seem to share the same address?

Update:

From the comments I understand that this has to do with the difference between `vector<bool>` and other `vector`s. Are there any other special cases about `vector` I should be aware of, or is `vector<bool>` the only one I need to watch out for?

Comment: `std::vector<bool>` is a specialization that usually stores bits in a compact way. It's really very different from any other vector.

Comment: [`reference` is a class that simulates the behavior of references of a single bit in `vector<bool>`.](http://eel.is/c++draft/vector.bool#4.sentence-1) Note that you are printing the address of an object of that `reference` class.

Comment: Oh my... I was thinking "surely `&a->isInfluenced[i]` shouldn't compile, it's taking the address of a temporary"... After putting it to the test, the proxy type (`std::__1::__bit_reference<...>` here) actually overloads `operator &` to return a `std::__1::__bit_iterator<...>`... What a wretched container-oid.

Comment: Recommended read: [On `vector<bool>`](https://howardhinnant.github.io/onvectorbool.html)

Comment: As you find in https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector `std::vector<bool>` is the only specialized vector.

Comment: a bool costs only one 1 bit, why spread it all over 3 or 8 bytes?

Comment: @Dr.Cutner To make `vector<bool>` a Container.

Comment: @Dr.Cutner for consistency with other containers, for consistency with the rest of `std::vector`, for `operator[]` to return a actual reference to 1 element and not a proxy, for fast iteration, access and modification, for avoiding surprising behaviors and for the absence of the wtf moments. And if you want a space-efficient array of bool then a different container like bitset should have been used. In retrospect `std::vector<bool>` is one of the most unfortunate decision of C++.

Comment: @bolov It can (in theory) be a massive performance boost (see Hinnant's article). But on balance I'm kind of surprised this hasn't been deprecated yet. I suppose one reason might be that they could never remove the specialisation outright, so deprecation is the beginning of an unclear path.

Answer (score 19):

They don't. Well, they do…

`vector<bool>` is not like other vectors.

The elements of a `vector<bool>` cannot be directly accessed like this, because they are/may be smaller than a byte, which is the "resolution" of addresses in C++. So many bits/elements are packed into a single memory location on your computer. But that's not why you get these results.

You're sort of observing the address of a temporary. That temporary is some proxy object that provides mutable access to a single *bit* in your collection.

I say "sort of" because you're not even really taking the address; said proxy object has an `operator&` that gives you something called a "bit iterator" in some implementations.

Here's [Howard Hinnant on `vector<bool>`](https://howardhinnant.github.io/onvectorbool.html).

In the meantime, when working with `vector<bool>`, unlearn what you know about vectors.

---

> Are there any other special cases about `vector` I should be aware of, or is `vector<bool>` the only one I need to watch out for?

`vector<bool>` is the only one.

Comment: `reference` doesn't have a `operator&`.

Comment: @L.F. it does... in some implementations, as mentioned. Which is just scary to me.

Comment: @L.F. Not a mandated one but at least one impl makes `&` work in that way (per Quentin's comment under the question).

Comment: @Quentin Really!  Is that conforming?  I think that modifies observable behavior.

Comment: @L.F. no idea. I just went to [Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/xwuvmFXPNFUlz4Sf) to see why this wasn't a "taking address of rvalue" error, and presto, `&a->isInfluenced[i]` returned `std::__1::__bit_iterator<...>`...

Comment: @L.F. Possibly so.

Comment: Nitpicking: "vector<bool> is the only one."  Actually vector<bool, A>

Comment: Your first line sounds like a case of ["Well yes, but actually no."](https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/well-yes-but-actually-no) :p great answer!

Comment: @scohe001 Also channeling the Tenth Doctor a little there. Weeell, I'm not. Weell, I am... ;)

Answer (score 1):

`std::vector<bool>::operator[]` is **not** returning a `bool&` as you might expect from normal vectors, it is returning a `std::vector<bool>::reference`.

`std::vector<bool>::reference` is a proxy object containing information about what bit it is referencing. Using this information, it supports a couple of operations to make it *almost* behave like a `bool&`. [std::vector<bool>::reference on cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool/reference)

When you do `&(a->childInds[i])`, you take the address of the r-value `std::vector<bool>::reference` object. In your case the compiler is reusing the memory on the second call to operator[], and therefore prints the same address.

This is the only specialization of std::vector.